# Windows Phone 8 SDK Xde emulator runs really slow and Crashes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

when you try and run the emulator it will load, then say windows phone OS is starting up, then sit there about 3-5 mins and fail. 
Im Running Visual Studio Express 2012 for WP on Lenovo N586 64-bit I've upgraded to windows 8 pro

lemme run down the list of what Ive tried...all are listed [here](http://igrali.com/2012/10/31/windows-phone-8-emulator-wasnt-able-to-create-the-virtual-machine/)

1. yes hardware supports hyper-v virtualiztion amd a6-4400m
2. I'm slat Capable theres a program you can use to test this.
3. Hyper-v is Installed and running fine
4. running windows 8 pro I had to upgrade.
5. Im 64 bit
6. Im not running any other virtualization software
7. Ive run XDEcleanup.exe and ran VS2012 as administrator no luck
8. no im not running on a virtual machine.
9. and just for fun I've uninstalled the sdk and re installed it

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For what you're describing, its looks like the VS is trying to create the virtual switch, but failed. To resolve this, go to Hyper-V's Virtual Switch Manager, on the left side of the window, and be sure that you have one virtual switch for every network card you have, usually you must have 3: 1 for the wireless, 1 for the LAN and 1 for internal. If your don't have the wireless or the LAN, create them.